# elsarticle.cls: How to change the symbol used in \fnref

Tags: elsarticle

`\fnref` is automatically labeled by a number, how can I change it to a symbol instead like #?

```
    \documentclass{elsarticle}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frontmatter}
    \title{This is a title}
    \author[address1]{M. Author1 \fnref{fn1}}
    \author[address1]{M. Author2 \fnref{fn1}}
    \fntext[fn1]{This author contributed equally to this work.}
    \address[address1]{some addresses.}
    \end{frontmatter}
    \section{Paper Material}
    Some Text.
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\thefootnote` in macro `\fntext` is incorrecty defined as `\c@fnote`, which results in an error for non-arabic counters. This is now modified to `\thefnote`.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\thefnote{\myfnsymbol{fnote}}}
\makeatletter
\def\myfnsymbol#1{\expandafter\@myfnsymbol\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@myfnsymbol#1{\ifcase #1\or $\#$\or $\#\#$\else \@ctrerr\fi}
\def\fntext[#1]#2{\g@addto@macro\@fnotes{%
   \refstepcounter{fnote}\elsLabel{#1}%
   \def\thefootnote{\thefnote}% <-- corrected
   \global\setcounter{footnote}{\c@fnote}%
   \footnotetext{#2}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
  \title{This is a title}
  \author[address1]{M. Author1 \corref{ca1}\fnref{fn1}}
  \cortext[ca1]{Corresponding author}
  \author[address1]{M. Author2 \fnref{fn1}}
  \fntext[fn1]{This author contributed equally to this work.}
  \address[address1]{some addresses.}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Paper Material}
Some Text.

\end{document}
```

[image]